# how to set delay for one day firebase job dispatcher

Tags: android, firebase-job-dispatcher

I'm trying to execute background task using firebase job dispatcher, problem is that app will run on kit to oreo, and I want to execute the job in the background on daily basis in a specific define time. for example, if I job set at 7 am and the current time is 5 pm then function executing after two hours, but I want to execute 7 pm on every day,

```
 FirebaseJobDispatcher firebaseJobDispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new 
     GooglePlayDriver(context));

        Calendar  now = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"),

                       Locale.getDefault());

        Calendar fixTime = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"),
                       Locale.getDefault());

               fixTime.set(Calendar.HOUR, 7);
               fixTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
               fixTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
               fixTime.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);

             long diff = fixTime.getTimeInMillis() - now.getTimeInMillis() ;
             int seconds = (int) Math.abs(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(diff));


          Job networkJob = firebaseJobDispatcher.newJobBuilder()
                       .setService(NotificationJobService.class)
                       .setTag(myJobTag)
                       .setRecurring(true)
                       .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow( seconds, seconds+40))
                       .setLifetime(Lifetime.FOREVER)
                       .setReplaceCurrent(true)
                       .setRetryStrategy(RetryStrategy.DEFAULT_EXPONENTIAL)
                       .build();

               firebaseJobDispatcher.schedule(networkJob);
```

Comment: `Firebase-job-dispatcher` does not run precisely. Rather you should go for `alarmManager ` to exact trigger!

Comment: Thanks for response, is alarm manager working  properly in oreo

Comment: alarmmanager doesnt work when the app is killed. :/ Doze mode constraints.